# writing data from a program to a file

Tags: linux, piping

I'm using linux.  Let's say I have a program named add. The program takes two numbers.

so if I type in

```
add 1 2
```

the answer is 3 //obvious

what command will make this write out to a file named add.data

I'm kind of a linux n00b.  I was reading about piping.  Thanks.

Comment: no need to ask whether its homework. someone is bound to answer whether or not it is. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Piping** means sending the output of a program as input to a second, which must be able to read data from the standard input, e.g.

```
add 1 2 | echo
```

What you are asking about here is **output redirection**: you should use

```
add 1 2 > add.data
```

to create a new file with your output (if existing will be overwritten), and

```
add 1 2 >> add.data
```

to create a new one or append to an existing.

Answer (score 1):

add 2 3 > something.txt

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect output into a file, recreates the file every time

```
add 1 2 > add.data
```

This will append to the end of the file

```
add 1 2 >> add.data
```

Comment: This is redirection, *not* piping.